# Styled Maps: How can I control visibility of elements for specific zoom level?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I am trying to create a styled map with map stylers in Goolge Maps API v3. Everything is working fine, except that I can't find a way to add styles for elements at a specific zoom level.

For example, I only want the `road.highway` displayed at a higher zoom level, otherwise the whole map is cluttered with highways. I have tried to use the `weight` property, but that makes the highways thinner even if on a high zoom level.

Is there a way how this can be done, if so, could you please show me how to do it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done by creating different google.maps.StyledMapType objects with different styles, and then setting an event listener to listen to the 'zoom_changed' event of the Map object. This should give you some idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Custom Styled Map</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

/***
SEE:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
ALSO, GOOGLES STYLED MAP WIZARD:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html
***/

function initialize() {
    var gm = google.maps,
        darkStylers = [
            {stylers:[{invert_lightness:true}]}
        ],
        lightStylers = [
            {stylers:[{saturation:-100}]}
        ],
        darkStyle = new gm.StyledMapType(darkStylers, {name: 'Dark Style'}),
        lightStyle = new gm.StyledMapType(lightStylers, {name: 'Light Style'}),
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            center: new gm.LatLng(32.8297,-96.6486),
            mapTypeId: gm.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        },
        map = new gm.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    //add two new MapTypes to the maps mapTypes
    map.mapTypes.set('Dark_Map', darkStyle);
    map.mapTypes.set('Light_Map', lightStyle);
    //set our maps initial style
    map.setMapTypeId('Dark_Map');
    gm.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
        var zoom = this.getZoom();
        if (zoom < 9) {
            map.setMapTypeId('Dark_Map');
        } else {
            map.setMapTypeId('Light_Map');
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:780px; height:600px; margin:10px auto;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't think about doing it programmatically. I thought there was just a property to set the importance or something like this. But your solution is certainly a great idea!

Comment: I am trying to make the state labels (administrative.province) visible at higher zoom levels, and as far as I can tell this is not possible, even with switching out the styles programmatically. I'd love to find a way to control the visibility of certain elements (labels) at specific zoom levels using the stylers, but it looks like that's not a part of the API. ... I'd love to be proven wrong!

Comment: @Sam H, To the best of my knowledge there is no way via the default api to switch them at minimal zoom levels of 0, 1 & 2 as I see it. Don't know why you'd want the labels then anyhow, you are up at astronauts view level and labels would have to be so tiny in order to fit between each other that you could not read them well at all. You could actually add your own labels I suppose, perhaps have a play with: https://github.com/erunyon/ELabel or else make your own custom overlay