# Styled Maps: Enabling MapTypeStyleFeatureType on different zoom levels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I am looking for a way to enable [MapTypeStyleFeatureType's](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) on varying zoom-levels of a map, which proves to be either well hidden or just not possible.

In my scenario at hand I am looking at a map of Germany, fully displayed as 560x600px at zoom 6 – at this zoom level the MapTypeStyleFeatureType administrative.province is not visible. It is visible at 7 and higher.

As a zoomlevel of 7 is not properly displaying whole Germany, I have been looking for a way to enable administrative.province at a lower zoom level – unfortunately I haven't found anything that seemed to work and/or promised to work.

I experimented a while using the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), but as this wizard doesn't adjust the basemap per se, it isn't capable of this task.
I stumbled upon the question "[Styled Maps: How can I control visibility of elements for specific zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028633/styled-maps-how-can-i-control-visibility-of-elements-for-specific-zoom-level)", but it adjusts the visibility within the possible range and doesn't try to change the range as such. As the user "astupidname" implies in the comments of that question it seems to be impossible.

Did anyone else already have this kind of problem and found a working solution – or can it be accepted as fact that the google API doesn't provide the tools to solve this task?
I would be grateful for any kind of hint/help!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  If it is just the province labels, possibly you could use [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html) to display those yourself, then turn off the "administrative.province" in the map styling.

Comment: I want the strokes to be visible at lower zoom levels, as they start to appear at 7 and higher – I need them at 6 and lower

Comment: What do you mean by "strokes"? The boundaries of the provinces?

Comment: Yes, those are of the feature type administrative.province and element type geometry.stroke.